# Sort List<Point> ListOfPoints that reside on a straight line in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, point

We have a list of `Points` which all reside on a straight line.

```
var pt1 = new Point(500,100);
var pt2 = new Point(0,0);
var pt3 = new Point(1000,200);

List<Point> ListOfPoints = new List<Point> {pt1, pt2, pt3}
```

How can we sort these points so that if we consider pt2 (start point of this imaginary line) as the base point, all the other points are sorted after each other on this imaginary straight line?

it should look like below in this case after sorting

```
x------------x-----------x
pt2          pt1         pt3
```

Comment: Define what you mean by sorting for a 2d point

Comment: @Xiaoy312 See pt2(0,0) is the start point of this imaginary line, the next point is pt1 and finally we have pt3 as the end point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sice all points are on a straight line, you can sort them by X-Coordinate and then by Y-coordinate (if line goes straight up, because in this case all X-Coordinates are equal):

```
ListOfPoints.OrderBy(pt => pt.X).ThenBy(pt => pt.Y).ToList();
```

Comment: Thats assuming an awful lot about the slope of the line. A good answer for positive slope though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: what is slope?

Comment: The line has a slope and it can be positive or negative. Will this be able to deal with it?

Comment: @FlatEric `slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2-x1)`

Comment: Since the question says 'all points are on a straight line', I don't see any problems

Comment: Thanks Eric, Actually your solution is working very well, and it is a very genius answer actually.

Answer (score 0):

> See pt2(0,0) is the start point of this imaginary line, the next point
>   is pt1 and finally we have pt3 as the end point.

You need to provide more detail on how you consider it as sorted. All these sort fit into your example.

```
var sort1 = ListOfPoints.OrderBy(p => p.X)
var sort2 = ListOfPoints.OrderBy(p => p.Y)
var sort3 = ListOfPoints.OrderBy(p => p.X * p.Y)
var sort4 = ListOfPoints.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(pt => p.Y)
```

If these points belong in a cartesian coordinate system, I think you should use the `sort1` unless you have other requirements.

Comment: Then `sort1` should do the job for you.

Comment: @No it won't for lines along the Y axis, but sort4 will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the points are Int's, then above solution will work for sure. If it's a floating point, then the following approach might be better to get rid of nasty cases.

```cs
Vector2 sp = pts.First();
Vector2 ep = pts.Last();
Vector2 plLineVe = (ep - sp);
double len = plLineVe.LengthSqr();
List<double> uVal = new List<double>();
for (int ll = 0; ll < pts.Count; ll++)
{
    double u = (pts[ll].x - sp.x) * (ep.x - sp.x) + (pts[ll].y - sp.y) * (ep.y - sp.y);
    u = u / len;
    uVal.Add(u);
}
uVal.Sort();
double x = sp.x + uVal.First() * plLineVe.x;
double y = sp.y + uVal.First() * plLineVe.y;
Vector2 s = new Vector2(x, y);
x = sp.x + uVal.Last() * plLineVe.x;
y = sp.y + uVal.Last() * plLineVe.y;
Vector2 e = new Vector2(x, y);
```